# how can I get specific word from a text dictionary file stored in raw folder;

Tags: android

I'm using a txt file as database and I want to search the contents of file for specific string(word), and if exists to add it on a listview. I've manage to achive the most part using the above code:

**Read the file**

```
public String readTxt(){

     InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.words);
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     int i;
    try {
    i = inputStream.read();
    while (i != -1)
      {
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
       i = inputStream.read();
      }
      inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

     return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
```

**Trying to search for string**

```
if(readTxt().contains(word)){
        addWord.add(new String(word));
```

The problem is that I cannot search for whole words. If I use the above way, I get everything contains string' s characters. For e.g if the word is LETTER, I get a match, but I also get a match if the word is  TTE.
I've search here and tried some different approaches which discribed but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change .contains(word); to .contains(" " + word + " ");.

Comment: Doesn' t work, I don't get any word like this(even if exists on txt file). I've also tried .contains("" + word + "") and with /b character, which doesn't work either

Comment: Well how are the words in your file separated? Not by spaces? How is that file build up then?

Comment: The file has the words one by line, and there is no space after a word.

Comment: So the words are sparated by \n or by \r\n. So try .contains("\n" + word + "\n"); first and then the other.

Comment: Thank you for point this out. I've already changed one of the txt files with notepad++ to have spaces and worked. I've completely forget to think about line changes, I thought that was spaces. I'll try with /n on another file, but I'm pretty sure it will work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression pattern matcher to match whole words.  This one splits a message into 160 character chunks, but you can easily modify it to find a "whole word".

```
protected ArrayList<String> splitMsg(SmsMessage smsMessage) {
        ArrayList<String> smt;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{1,160}");
        Matcher regexMatcher = p.matcher(smsMessage.getMsgBody());
        smt = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            smt.add(regexMatcher.group());
        }
        return smt;
    }
```